# In OpenGL, is there a way to blend based on a separate channel's value in the shader?

Tags: opengl, graphics, fragment-shader

In OpenGL (not ES), is there a universal way to blend based a texture while drawing based on another texture or variable's value? On OpenGLES, I know that I can do custom blending on some platforms via extensions like GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch. The reason I ask, is that I have a special texture where the forth channel is not alpha, and I need to be able to blend it on a separate alpha which is available on a different map.

Comment: Yeah Dolphin uses that extension as a fallback for dual-source blending: https://github.com/dolphin-emu/dolphin/commit/29a9ed043bd0946497edf7c4d392ce46041b9817

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want dual-source blending, which is available in core as of OpenGL 3.3.  This allows you to provide a fragment shader with two outputs and use both of them in the blend function.

You would declare outputs in the fragment shader like this:

```
layout(location = 0, index = 0) out vec4 outColor;
layout(location = 0, index = 1) out vec4 outAlpha;
```

You could then set the blending function like this, for premultiplied alpha:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC1_COLOR);
```

Or non-premultiplied alpha:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC1_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC1_COLOR);
```

Note that `SRC1` here is the second output of the fragment shader.  If I remember correctly, this blending will only work for one location.

Comment: "*If I remember correctly, this blending will only work for one location.*" For all practical purposes, this is true. But it is a hardware limitation, not an API limitation. You can [query how many locations you get with dual-source blending](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending#Dual_Source_Blending), which is a different limit when not using non-dual-source blending. It's just that, for pretty much all current hardware that supports it, that limit will be 1.